# Issues with pdftk on bluehost

Tags: php, pdftk, bluehost

I am trying to fill fields in pdf forms based on user data for a site on bluehost. I had it working about a month ago using pdftk. Yesterday for some reason it is not working at all. I then tried running it from the command line and am getting the following error.

./pdftk: error while loading shared libraries: libgcj.so.7rh: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I have been bashing my head against this for a few hours no to no avail.

Is there any way to fix this on bluehost? I tried manually installing the library, but I can not access /var/lib and I also can not force it to install elsewhere

[~/lib/temp]# rpm -i libgcj-4.1.2-51.SEL5_5.x86_64.rpm
warning: libgcj-4.1.2-51.SEL5_5.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 652e84dc: NOKEY
error: can't create transaction lock on /var/lib/rpm/.rpm.lock (Permission denied)

[~/lib/temp]# rpm -i --prefix ~/lib/rpm libgcj-4.1.2-51.SEL5_5.x86_64.rpm
warning: libgcj-4.1.2-51.SEL5_5.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 652e84dc: NOKEY
error: package libgcj is not relocatable

Alternatively, is ther any other way of filling pdf files that I am missing? I have looked into Horde PDF, forge_fdf and others and nothing is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that they just upgraded their server's OS, and yes the CentOS upgrade caused this. But you should be able to get a Cent 6 rpm of the offending lib and the pdftk command and do what ever you did before to make it work.  It's probably on of the following:

libgcj-4.4.6-3.el6.x86_64 or 
libgcj-4.1.2-51.el5

/usr/lib64/libgcj.so.10 = looks like that is the new library path

But contact them to find out which one, or which ones.

Comment: Looks like that was the case... Thanks.   
From Bluehost:   
*We upgraded from centOS 5 to centOS 6 on 02/12/2012 for your particular server.  Some of the shared libraries on the server were also changed at this time.  /usr/lib64/libgcj.so.10 is the changed library for the previously used /usr/lib64/libgcj.so.7rh one.  You may need to recompile your binary /bin/pdftk to use that changed library now.*
   
Now I just need to figure out how to do that last part and recompile pdftk.  Off to the Googles!

Comment: Having issues trying to figure out where I change the library that is referenced before I recompile. I opened a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519023/compile-pdftk-with-libgcj-so-10-on-centos-redhat, but if you have any suggestions, I'm all ears...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like bluehost changed something in your account or server. I would try calling them or doing a live chat with them, I've had good results with their technicians.