# Compile pdftk with /libgcj.so.10 on centOS (Redhat)

Tags: java, php, pdftk, gcj, libgcj

Has anyone successfully complied pdftk with the /libgcj.so.10 library? Bluehost upgraded from centOS 5 to centOS6 and blew away the library I needed, telling me this is the new one. I took a look in the makefiles (Makefile.Redhat, Makefile.Base and the java Makefile), but I can't seem to find where I would point to the new library.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who ends up here specifically for pdftk on Bluehost, I got on the forum and they have installed it for Bluehost in /usr/bin and everything seems to be working well now.  Just call pdftk directly.

For people looking for a build for CentOS 6, I did find this page with rpms for multiple versions of CentOS with 6 towards the bottom. I was not able to actually install it, so I can't speak to their validity, but it should get you started.